# In what better example can represent a switch statement in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm sure there are better examples than mine:)

Let's say that it's snowing and the users can earn points for each snowflake, but they have to do it fast to no get stuck in the snow, so this is my ex:

```
class apples{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int points;
        points = 1;

        switch (points){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("32");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Almost half");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You're near");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Congratulations., You got 100 points");
        default:
            System.out.println("Want to start again?");
        break;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Curiuos to see the rest of the story...
By now the program does nothing more than `sysout("32")`

Comment: @ Andreas - I guess that i have not explained well ., this is just a example of a switch statement, what i mean is to show nice examples to have future better ideas on how to use it ., thanks

Comment: I wish you luck, there's almost no valid reason to use `switch` in any modern (read oop) language these days.. You might be better served looking up design patterns to replace them.

Comment: @ Blindy - Is a better way ? Can you show a example to run it in Java ?

Comment: @vili82, I would recommend you to read the Java trail as you seem, to me, that you are barely starting with Java. Knowing how to "make it run" falls outside your question here.

Comment: Yes i strating with Java, but i controled almost all codes that i run in Eclipse ., ok with 2 o 3 excepcions, but in this case if i put the same code that you tell me, why gives me the error of screenshots !?

Comment: @vili82, he is referring to using subclasses to distinguish behaviour instead of using switch statements.

Comment: There is a bug, it should print out "42" instead of "32."

Comment: Add a screnshot please to see it

Answer (score 4):

The switch statement has been miss-used for a long time.

The original idea was to have an entry point system; a `goto`-like statement which worked like this :

```
If my value is 1; goto 1;
Else If my value is 2; goto 2;
Else If my value is 3; goto 3;
Else If goto default;
label 1 : ...;
label 2 : ...;
label 3 : ...;
label default : ...;
```

And people started to like this system and decided that it would be better than having a lot of if/else statements. So they used a little trick, the `break;` And now people really enjoy the switch as a replacement of the if/else by breaking every case of the switch.

To have a really good example of the original switch statement, you should have something like this:

```
public void printDaysLeftUntilNextMonday(){
    switch(dayOfWeek){
        case 1 :
            System.out.println("Monday");
        case 2 :
            System.out.println("Tuesday");
        case 3 :
            System.out.println("Wednesday");
        case 4 :
            System.out.println("Thursday");
        case 5 :
            System.out.println("Friday");
        case 6 :
            System.out.println("Saturday");
        case 7 :
            System.out.println("Sunday");
    }
}
```

I had a real use case on day (rare thing if you don't abuse of break; in switch) it was in a Hangman.

```
public void printHangman(){
    switch(triesLeft){
        case 1 :
            printLeftLeg();
        case 2 :
            printRightLeg();
        case 3 :
            printLeftArm();
        case 4 :
            printRightArm();
        case 5 :
            printBody();
        case 6 :
            printHead();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, in Java, if dayOfWeek == 1, then it will output all the days of the week. This is not helping.

Comment: If we're monday, you will see all the days to next monday (@see method name). I added a second example more precise.

Comment: don't forget the `break;` statements

Comment: @vili82 what part doesn't work ? It's a simple use case, it's not intended to really run as is.

@Andreas that's the point

Comment: I put the break; statements and is not work ., can you try to run this code ?

Comment: @vili82 Did you put in a class?

Comment: where ? what class ? in the beginning class apples{ etc .??

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have more flexibility than a `HashMap` (not that there's anything wrong with the solution), you can go with a chain of responsibility :

```
class PointScore {
   private PointScore next;
   private int points;
   private String msg;

   public PointScore(int points, String msg) {
      this.points = points;
      this.msg = msg;
      this.next = null;
   }

   public PointScore setNext(PointScore next) {
      this.next = next;
      return next;
   }

   public boolean checkScore(int points) {
      if (this.points == points) {
         System.out.println(this.msg);
         return true;
      } else if (null != next) {
         return next.checkScore(points);
      } else {
         return false;
      }

   }

}
```

Then your main entry point :

```
class Apples {

   public static void main(String...args) {
      int points;
      points = 1;

      // set first condition (highest priority first)
      PointScore scores = new PointScore(4, "Congratulations., You got 100 points");
      // set next chain members in order or priority (highest to lowest)
      scores.setNext(new PointScore(3, "You're near"))
         .setNext(new PointScore(2, "Almost half"))
         .setNext(new PointScore(1, "32"));

      if (!scores.checkScore(points)) {
         System.out.println("Want to start again?");
      }
   }
}
```

This doesn't look much, but the `checkScore` method can perform other checks; for example, you could setup a range of values instead of a single `points` integer, etc.

Comment: He gives me a error in eclipse with:

if (this.points = points){


.., i don't now way

Comment: LOL typo, it should be == , I fixed it :) I wrote that in the textarea without testing it

Comment: I don't know what you did, but I just tried it (for the first time) and it printed out 32. The screenshot you give shows that you have an error somewhere, but I don't know what it is. My best guess is that your file is named 'apples.java' and it should be 'Apples.java' since class names should start with an upper case letter and a source file must be named as one of the contained class name.

Comment: just noticed I had a problem when creating the chain, my mistake. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yanick is not work ., can you attach a screeanshot to see that you run this code

Comment: just create Apples.java and copy/paste all the code inside. There's nothing more to it

Comment: please also copy the PointScore class below your class Apples, or even better, create another file (PointScore.java - case sensitive) in the same package.

Comment: here is your code http://yfrog.com/5nsqa1p and when i run it still give me the same error http://yfrog.com/16sqa2p

Comment: your launch configuration may still have 'apples' as startup class. You need to change it. I usually right click on the class to run (Apples.java) and select "Run as..." > "Java application"

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary or a hashmap to map the number of points to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Okay here we go. At work we often use **enum** types, simple example:

```
public enum Colors {
   RED,
   GREEN,
   BLUE,
   YELLOW,
   VIOLET,
   BROWN,
   ORANGE; // more to come
}
```

so we can switch over these literal constants:

```
public String colorToMood(final Colors color) {
    String mood = "everything the same to me";
    switch (color) {
      case RED:
        mood = "excited";
        break;
      case YELLOW:
        mood = "I like the sun";
        break;
      case GREEN:
        mood = "forests are nice";
        break;
      case BLUE:
        mood = "I feel free like a bird in the sky";
        break;
      // fill in your code here for VIOLET, BROWN, ORANGE
      // otherwise they get handled by the default clause
      default:
        mood = "I don't know your color";
        break;
    }
    return mood;
}
```

Maybe you now get a better idea what the benefits of a switch in conjunction with enums are. You can even define a constructor for your enum constants, but that gets too advanced...

Comment: Of course this code will not work for you. You have to have the mentioned types ready, need at least stubs for the methods seen and after all, have a second look: the method does not return anything.

You could easily make your own example. I've edited my post to a simpler example.

Comment: @ Andreas But i want to work for me ., i want to run and to test it ., i want to learn very good this leanguege ., i just started, for this reason always i ask for good respons about the codes THAT CAN BE TASTED to see and understand better how they work and all connections between them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I find switch statements make most sense when the range of a variable is bounded. So for example the days-of-the-week example given here is fine, and the one with the enum is even better.

Bit of a no-brainer, but [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) has an excellent page with the history, advantages and disadvantages of the switch statement, as well as a host of examples in different languages.

Comment: Show an example Michael of switch statements that you have used

Comment: Uhm... If you don't mind shameless self-promotion you can try my article over here: http://whiteboxcomputing.com/java/enum_factory/
It contains a real-life example of a switch statement about halfway down the page.

Comment: Tomorrow I see it, now I'm dead tired .. 04:00 am here